# Receiving 414 When Hitting Firebase Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, salesforce, apex

I am receiving an error when posting to my google cloud function - from salesforce execute anonymous - which just takes in the request an saves the body in the Firestore.

414 URI Too Long is the response status.

The error doesn't make sense because the url i am hitting is 60 characters long including https://.

So I think this means that my body is too large because i don't get the same error when posting a smaller body.

So my question is: Is there a way to change the default size limit for incoming requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 414 response was from Salesforce, not from Firebase. I was using the execute anonymous window to post this request and it turns out that there is a limit when executing code this way. I was able to submit my request using the salesforce cli command sfdx force:execute instead.